# Pandas reindex to higher resolution

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reindex

I have a pandas dataframe with index 3 to 15 with 0.5 steps and want to reindex it to 0.1 steps.
I tried this code and it doesn't work

```
# create data and set index and print for verification
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.arange(3,5,0.5),'B':np.arange(3,5,0.5)})
df.set_index('A', inplace = True)
df.reindex(np.arange(3,5,0.1)).head(15)
```

The above code outputs this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 3.0 | 3.0 |
| 3.1 | NaN |
| 3.2 | NaN |
| 3.3 | NaN |
| 3.4 | NaN |
| 3.5 | NaN * expected output in this position to be 3.5 since it exists in the original df |
| 3.6 | NaN |
| 3.7 | NaN |
| 3.8 | NaN |

Strangely the problem is fixed when reindexing from 0 instead of 3 as it's shown in the code below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.arange(3,5,0.5),'B':np.arange(3,5,0.5)})
df.set_index('A', inplace = True)
print(df.head())
df.reindex(np.arange(0,5,0.1)).head(60)
```

The output now correctly shows

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 0.0 | NaN |
| ... | ... |
| 3.0 | 3.0 |
| 3.1 | NaN |
| 3.2 | NaN |
| 3.3 | NaN |
| 3.4 | NaN |
| 3.5 | 3.5 |
| 3.6 | NaN |
| 3.7 | NaN |
| 3.8 | NaN |

I'm running python 3.8.5 on Windows 10.

Pandas version is 1.4.07

Numpy version is 1.22.1

Does anyone know why this happens? If it's a known or new bug? If the bug has been fixed in a newer version of python, pandas or numpy?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.

The answer is because `np.arange(3,5,0.1)` creates a value of 3.5 that is not exactly 3.5.  It is 3.5000000000000004.  But `np.arange(0,5,0.1)` does create a 3.5 that is exactly 3.5.  Plus, `np.arange(3,5,0.5)` also generates a 3.5 that is exactly 3.5.

```
pd.Index(np.arange(3,5,0.1)) 

Float64Index([               3.0,                3.1,                3.2,
              3.3000000000000003, 3.4000000000000004, 3.5000000000000004,
              3.6000000000000005, 3.7000000000000006, 3.8000000000000007,
               3.900000000000001,  4.000000000000001,  4.100000000000001,
               4.200000000000001,  4.300000000000001,  4.400000000000001,
               4.500000000000002,  4.600000000000001,  4.700000000000001,
               4.800000000000002,  4.900000000000002],
             dtype='float64')
```

and

```
pd.Index(np.arange(0,5,0.1))

Float64Index([                0.0,                 0.1,                 0.2,
              0.30000000000000004,                 0.4,                 0.5,
               0.6000000000000001,  0.7000000000000001,                 0.8,
                              0.9,                 1.0,                 1.1,
               1.2000000000000002,                 1.3,  1.4000000000000001,
                              1.5,                 1.6,  1.7000000000000002,
                              1.8,  1.9000000000000001,                 2.0,
                              2.1,                 2.2,  2.3000000000000003,
               2.4000000000000004,                 2.5,                 2.6,
                              2.7,  2.8000000000000003,  2.9000000000000004,
                              3.0,                 3.1,                 3.2,
               3.3000000000000003,  3.4000000000000004,                 3.5,
                              3.6,                 3.7,  3.8000000000000003,
               3.9000000000000004,                 4.0,  4.1000000000000005,
                              4.2,                 4.3,                 4.4,
                              4.5,  4.6000000000000005,                 4.7,
                4.800000000000001,                 4.9],
             dtype='float64')
```

and

```
pd.Index(np.arange(3,5,0.5))

Float64Index([3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5], dtype='float64')
```

This is definitely related to `Numpy`:

```
np.arange(3,5,0.1)[5]

3.5000000000000004
```

and

```
np.arange(3,5,0.1)[5] == 3.5

False
```

This situation is documented in the `Numpy arange` doc:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html

> The length of the output might not be numerically stable.
>
> Another stability issue is due to the internal implementation of
> numpy.arange. The actual step value used to populate the array is
> dtype(start + step) - dtype(start) and not step. Precision loss can
> occur here, due to casting or due to using floating points when start
> is much larger than step. This can lead to unexpected behaviour.

It looks like `np.linspace` might be able to help you out here:

```
pd.Index(np.linspace(3,5,num=21))

Float64Index([3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 4.0, 4.1, 4.2,
              4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7, 4.8, 4.9, 5.0],
             dtype='float64')
```